# Would weapon firing both recoilless projectiles and guided rockets be feasible?

Tags: internal-consistency, weapons

Idea for a weapon:

- hand held recoilless gun with caliber around ~75mm (to hit nearby, low value, easy to hit targets)
- to this weapon also anti-tank or anti-air guided rockets can be loaded (when dealing with more distant, resilient, valuable or mobile targets) Yes, they may partially stick out of the tube. (something like a bigger, guided brother of RPG)

My basic fact checking:

- normally rocket launchers (example: Stinger) use double engine anyway (first to leave the tube without burning user, second to actually deliver the projectile)
- using recoilless launch is actually doable for rocket projectile (example: RPG), but they seem to be much smaller

Would such weapon be feasible? (I wonder whether trade offs would actually be worth it or be an engineering nightmare) Yes, I know it would leave impressive backblast, this one is fine.

EDIT:

- modern tech level
- an example of a recoilless rifle:
  [image]

Comment: N.B.:  A "guided rocket" is a [missile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missile).  So, you basically want a [Recoilless Rifle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recoilless_rifle), with an [attached Grenade Launcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grenade_launcher#Attached) that fires small [MPADS missiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-portable_air-defense_system#Missile_models)

Comment: @Chronocidal I want a recoilless rifle that can also fire almost normal sized MPADS if possible. No grenade launcher attached.

Comment: What technological timeframe? Modern, near future, 70s? Also, is 75mm caliber a typo? That would almost immediately render it unfeasible as a handheld weapon simply because of size without accompanying tech advances like support exoskeletons

Comment: Adding to @nullpointer's comment above, 75 mm caliber is on par with that used by tanks. That's hardly handheld, nor recoilless, nor particularly likely to be limited in use to "nearby, low value, easy to hit" targets.

Comment: Are we to take that you edited the question, but left the caliber as it was, as a sign that 75 mm is the intended value?

Comment: Yes, actually in RL the most popular caliber for such handheld weapon is 84 mm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Gustaf_recoilless_rifle

Comment: When you say 'hand-held' do you mean one handed like a pistol, or two handed like a rifle/bazooka?

Comment: @Smock two-handed I guess, 75mm caliber is quite huge for a pistol.

Comment: It looks like the CG itself is a good example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Gustaf_recoilless_rifle#Ammunition

Comment: I would add the Carl Gustaf link to your question to guide people on how large a handheld recoilless rifle can be. Reading through the info the naming is off though. You have grenade launchers, then recoilless rifles/guns (guns have smoothbore and rifles have rifling).  These 3 all fire an unguided shell or grenade using propellant in the gun. Then come rocketlaunchers which are recoilless guns that fire a self-propelled grenade or rocket. And lastly a missile launcher which is a rocketlauncher firing a guided rocket, which we call a missile.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fuZwou-AUBk heavier, but a hole lot safer than direct-fire on tanks & reinforced installations. m72 law & gustav effectively show that it (the meat of the question) can be done, no? or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you asking for a universal 75 mm shoulder-fired missile platform that can target all kind of targets?

Comment: You could I guess put guidance fins on the round to steer it toward the target, that seems like the cheapest way to do it from a recoiless rifle with thermal imaging guidance. It wouldn't be your traditional fire and forget seeker rocket, but it'd have certain adavantages over just a plain recoiless rifle round.

Comment: @Shadow1024 On hindsight I misunderstood "handheld" to be something completely different from what most other people would probably understand it to mean, so please ignore my previous comment

Comment: If this was already done then I VTC because its too broad, maybe a different timeline would help? or maybe put a scene on your story on where you want to use it, then we might give an alternative. As it stand right now I think it is pretty broad.

Comment: I do not get the question - the Carl Gustav launches recoilless. The projectiles it launches could be anything from missiles to mice - what is the specific technological hurdle you are trying to clear?

Answer (score 4):

## This already exists

The Carl Gustaf recoilless rifle, which you have pictured, has the option to fire ammunition which is both laser guided and rocket assisted.

Comment: Thanks for info, indeed they are being right now developed / start being produced. But it seems for me that I miss one key info - for over half century no one seriously tried to merge such two weapons. Any idea where is the catch?

Comment: @Shadow1024 If you mean merging anti-tank and anti-air functions, there has already been such an attempt known as the ADATS. Nobody knows how well it works though as AFAIK no shots were fired in anger before it was withdrawn from service

Answer (score 2):

You simply build a guided missile launcher that doesn't object if a dumb rocket is loaded into it.  When launching something guided you want to aim it as well as you can when launching anyway as such rounds have limited cross-range capability so the launcher will function the same in both cases.